# Dependency added to pom can not be resolved

Tags: java, maven, jfugue

I am trying to add a dependency to my pom.xml and facing an issue: IntelliJ error

> Cannot resolve jfugue:jfugue:5.0.9

The dependency I like to add is this one below from https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jfugue/jfugue/5.0.9

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jfugue/jfugue -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>jfugue</groupId>
    <artifactId>jfugue</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.9</version>
</dependency>
```

I have no problems adding other dependencies just by adding the xml-snippet from maven into my pom and refresh or reload all maven projects. For example I have this dependency in the same pom which is working fine:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jsoup/jsoup -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
    <version>1.14.3</version>
</dependency>
```

However, there is a note under the snippet which one can copy-paste, https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jfugue/jfugue/5.0.9

> Note: this artifact is located at SingGroup repository (https://maven.sing-group.org/repository/maven/)

What do I need to add to the pom so that I can use that dependency in my Project and get rid of the error?

> Cannot resolve jfugue:jfugue:5.0.9

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to let maven know, how it can find the artifact. Since it needs to search the SingGroup repository, you need to add that repository information to your pom as well. Check this out: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-repositories.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add the repository to your settings.xml [Maven Guide](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-repositories.html)

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>multi-repo</id>
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>MavenCentral</id>
                <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/</url>
            </repository>
            <repository>
                <id>MavenSing</id>
                <url>https://maven.sing-group.org/repository/maven//</url>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
     </profile>
 </profiles>
```

Comment: If the dependency is only required for a given project, it would be better to add repository details in the project pom instead of global settings.xml.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: Nice observation @Ankush

Answer (score 1):

This Lib is no longer on the Maven repo. I get same result when adding the dependency to my project's POM file. You can get the JAR file from this URL and then include it into your project's class path:

http://www.jfugue.org/download.html